# does the word "Option" have an analogue in Japanese

Tags: word-choice

In English, we use the word "option" in a wide array of situations with many different meanings. When speaking, I struggled to find a word that translated the meaning effectively. Some examples are:

> Giving up is not an option.

In this case I assume there is not a direct translation, and I have to use `あきらめるわけにはいかない` or something of the sort?

> There are many drink options at that restaurant.

This is another usage that confuses me. I feel like `たくさんの種類` maybe works, but that there is still a better way to say this.

> What are our options?

or

> That idea, won't work, we need to find another option.

This is the usage that really gets me. I am not aware of a word that   exists such that I can say, `僕らはほかの＜option＞を探さない/見つけないといけない`

Comment: 「選択肢」はだめだったんでしょうか・・・

Comment: I always thought that was more for, like multiple choice questions. No?

Comment: @chargerstriker Chocolateさん's suggestion works for the examples that you gave.

Comment: I drafted some examples with 選択 and 選択肢 for each of these bu my grammar might be off...

Answer (score 4):

The word 選択肢 can be used, possibly with small rephrasing, like this:

> - 諦めるという選択肢はない。
> - このレストランにはたくさんのドリンクの選択肢がある。
> - 我々の選択肢は何か？
> - その案はダメだ、別の選択肢を探さないと。

Still, 選択肢 is a relatively stiff word, and yes, something like 諦めるわけにはいかない may be a reasonable choice in casual speech. If you feel like avoiding 選択肢, you can say たくさんのドリンク**から選べる**, どんな**案**があるか, 別の**方法**を探そう, etc.